# denial of creation of new subnets by OPA

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, open-policy-agent, rego

I have the below rego code,

```
package terraform.analysis

import input as tfplan

# acceptable score for automated authorization
blast_radius = 5

# weights assigned for each operation on each resource-type
weights = {
    "aws_subnet": {"delete": 100, "create": 10, "modify": 1},
}

# Consider exactly these resource types in calculations
resource_types = {"aws_subnet"}

# Authorization holds if score for the plan is acceptable and no changes are made to IAM
default authz = false
authz {
    score < blast_radius
}


# Compute the score for a Terraform plan as the weighted sum of deletions, creations, modifications
score = s {
    all := [ x |
            some resource_type
            crud := weights[resource_type];
            del := crud["delete"] * num_deletes[resource_type];
            new := crud["create"] * num_creates[resource_type];
            mod := crud["modify"] * num_modifies[resource_type];
            x := del + new + mod
    ]
    s := sum(all)
}

####################
# Terraform Library
####################

# list of all resources of a given type
resources[resource_type] = all {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := [name |
        name:= tfplan.resource_changes[_]
        name.type == resource_type
    ]
}

# number of creations of resources of a given type
num_creates[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    creates := [res |  res:= all[_]; res.change.actions[_] == "create"]
    num := count(creates)
}


# number of deletions of resources of a given type
num_deletes[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    deletions := [res |  res:= all[_]; res.change.actions[_] == "delete"]
    num := count(deletions)
}

# number of modifications to resources of a given type
num_modifies[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [res |  res:= all[_]; res.change.actions[_] == "update"]
    num := count(modifies)
}
```

My main.tf file is as below

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

# DATA RESOURCES
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}
data "aws_kms_key" "rds_key" {
  key_id = "alias/rds_cluster_enryption_key"
}
resource "aws_vpc" "tf-aws-vn" {
  cidr_block = var.network_address_space
  tags       = local.common_tags
}
data "template_file" "public_cidrsubnet" {
  count    = var.subnet_count
  template = "$${cidrsubnet(vpc_cidr,8,current_count)}"
  vars = {
    vpc_cidr      = var.network_address_space
    current_count = count.index
  }
}
# RESOURCES
resource "aws_subnet" "tf-aws-sn" {
  count             = var.subnet_count
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.tf-aws-vn.id
  cidr_block        = data.template_file.public_cidrsubnet[count.index].rendered
  availability_zone = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, var.subnet_count)[count.index]
  tags              = local.common_tags
}
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnets" {
  name       = "rdsdbgroup"
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.tf-aws-sn[*].id
  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "tf-aws-rds-1" {
  cluster_identifier      = "aurora-cluster-1"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.03.2"
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.db_subnets.name
  database_name           = "cupday"
  master_username         = "administrator"
  master_password         = var.password
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
  storage_encrypted       = true
  kms_key_id              = data.aws_kms_key.rds_key.arn
}
```

S3 Backend is below:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-backend-20200102"
    key    = "test.plan"
    region = "ap-southeast-2"
  }
}
```

I proceeded as below:

```
terraform show -json > tfplan.json # Assuming this reads my test.plan from s3 buckets and writes to local tfplan.json
opa eval --format pretty --data terraform.rego --input tfplan.json "data.terraform.analysis.authz"
```

I get "true" as a response to any subnet creation for more than 2 subnets when I should expect it as false?

Note: Apologies in advance, I am a complete newbie to OPA but certainly getting inspired by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how `blast_radius = 5`, it seems reasonable that one, two, three or four subnets in the plan are considered allowed, no?

Comment: So should I decrease the value ? Anything more than 2 sub nets it should not allow.

Comment: @learner changing the `blast_radius` to 3 ought to do it then.